# What's the problem in this short user-defined function?

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

It says that "salary" is not defined or that i can't multiply this.
I want to have it with the def command so please just let it in this form just correct the mistakes, im completely new to it so just let it as easy as it is. Thank you very much :)

```
def computepay(Hours,RatePerHour):
    if float(Hours)-40<0:
        salary=float(Hours)*float(RatePerHour)
    else:
        salary=40.0*float(RatePerHour)+(float(Hours)-40.0)*float(RatePerHour*1.5)

Hours=input("Hours:\n")
RatePerHour=input("RatePerHour:\n")
computepay(Hours,RatePerHour)
print("Salary:")
print(salary)
```

I expect that someone could help me how this little program works correct

Comment: the RatePerHour is 10 in this example, but it gets multiplied by 1.5 after 40 hours of working.

Comment: Post the actual error message in full

Comment: salary=40.0*float(RatePerHour)+(float(Hours)-40.0)*float(RatePerHour*1.5)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: thank you guys, i got it now :) you helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return salary` and then assign this to a variable. Here's an improved version of your code:

```
def compute_pay(hours: float, rate_per_hour: float) -> float:
    if hours - 40 < 0:
        salary = hours * rate_per_hour
    else:
        salary = 40 * rate_per_hour + (hours - 40.0)* rate_per_hour * 1.5
    return salary  # This is the line you are missing!

hours = input("Hours:\n")
rate_per_hour=input("RatePerHour:\n")
computer_salary = computepay(float(hours), float(rate_per_hour))  # You also need to assign the output of a function to a variable, I've given it a different name from salary just to show you that this is a different variable from the one inside your function. Also, cast to float here so you don't have to do it all over your function. 
print(f"Salary: {computer_salary}")
```

The concept you need to learn here is called [scope](https://pythonspot.com/scope/).

Comment: You do the same error : float(RatePerHour*1.5), as well as input return a string and you don't convert it

Comment: @FlorianBernard oops, typo, forgot to cast

Answer (score 0):

You needed to return the calculated salary.

Also, simpler if you performed the float conversion on input.

```
def computepay(Hours,RatePerHour):
    if float(Hours)-40<0:
        salary=Hours*RatePerHour
    else:
        salary=40.0*RatePerHour+ (Hours-40.0)*(RatePerHour*1.5)
    return salary  # return value

Hours = float(input("Hours:\n"))  # float conversion
RatePerHour = float(input("RatePerHour:\n"))  # float conversion
salary = computepay(Hours,RatePerHour)
print("Salary:")
print(salary)
```

Comment: beat me by four seconds!

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent--been there.

Comment: You still have the error, you multiply a string :) I let you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction, and some explications follow.

```py
def computepay(Hours,RatePerHour): 
    salary = 0
    if float(Hours)-40<0:    
        salary=float(Hours)*float(RatePerHour) 
    else: 
        salary=40.0*float(RatePerHour)+(float(Hours)-40.0)*float(RatePerHour) *1.5) #<=== here you multiply with out turning rateperhour as float
    return salary 

Hours=input("Hours:\n") RatePerHour=input("RatePerHour:\n") 
salary = computepay(Hours,RatePerHour) 
print("Salary:") 
print(salary)
```

First, salary is a variable enclosed inside your function, it's not a avaliable outside of it.

Second, you get an error because you multiply a string by an integer. Convert it to float before.

```py
float(RatePerHour*1.5) #wrong
float(RatePerHour) *1.5 # correct
```